GitKraken: How to get multi-panel layout of git branches, commit history, files changed, and line changes?
I prefer SourceTree's layout which allows me to see all of these things in one view, clicking a changed file to view its hunked changes in a side panel.
GitKraken is close to this, but clicking a changed file opens a line changes panel over the panels of branches list and commit history, causing a lot more clicks when I'm trying to navigate around. The equivalent in SourceTree merely requires glancing around. Also, the line changes panel leaves a lot of open space on its right side, and I'm just not seeing how to dock it in a way that takes up less space while being able to see all the other things I mentioned in the title like SourceTree does.
SourceTree currently doesn't work with WSL, and has randomly been too buggy on setups over the years to use it reliably. While JetBrains' or VS Code's VCS layouts are good, they miss combining all the panels I use most of the time, causing a lot more clicks and time spent flipping back and forth to review things. GitKraken is currently the best thing I can find until SourceTree becomes better compatible and less buggy.
I've clicked around in GitKraken's interface, gone through its options, looked online and in GitKraken's documentation, but am not seeing how to make the line changes panel its own docked thing like while still seeing the other panels (mentioned in the title of this post) like SourceTree does in their view. SourceTree's is so nice and I don't see any reason other git GUIs couldn't or shouldn't do something like it.
Anyway, I didn't see a forum to post for this, and StackOverflow kept showing up, so here I am.
